# EditText não aceita KeyListener

Tags: java, android, eventos

Eae galera, estou tentando definir um listener para um EditText mas está dando erro.

Erro:
setKeyListener (android.text.method.KeyListener) in TextView cannot be applied
to (com.example.calculaarea.MainActivity)

Meu Código:

```
//Minha Main implementa a OnKeyListener e aqui passo ela ao EditText
this.mHolder.editLargura.setKeyListener(this);

//Essa é a implementaçao do método onKey
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Como eu poderia corrigir este erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo erro parece que a interface que a Activity implementa não é aquela que o método `setKeyListener()` espera.

Não sei se está a trocar o método ou se está a trocar a interface.

Se de facto quer usar o método [setKeyListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)) então a Activity tem de imolementar a interface [KeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html).

Se, por outro lado, quer usar a interface [OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) então o método a usar é [setOnKeyListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener(android.view.View.OnKeyListener))

Comment: Vlw cara eu não tinha prestado atenção no On